# How to find all possible subarrays of an array?

Tags: arrays, data-structures

Let's suppose I am given an array; `A[] = {1,2,3}` and I want to find all the sub-arrays of this array. The answer should be

```
{1}
{1,2}
{1,2,3}
{2}
{2,3}
{3}
```

How to find all possible subarrays of an array efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subarray of an array A is `A[i..j]` where `0 <= i <= j < n` where n is length of array.

In C language it can be calculated like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int len=sizeof(A)/sizeof(int);
    for( int i=0; i<len; i++ ){
        for( int j=i; j<len; j++ ){   // Now A[i..j] is the subarray
            for( int k=i; k<=j; k++ )
                printf("%d ", A[k]);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach has ```O(n^3)``` time complexity. Is this the most efficient approach? I think hashing would be a more suitable approach since the question is to find the subarrays ```efficiently```.

Comment: this approach is o(n)3 time complexity approach and is not an efficient way.

Answer (score 3):

We can use [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) function to find the all possible sub array.

### Code Snippet :

```
       #include<bits/stdc++.h>
       using namespace std;


       void generateSubstring(string str)
       {
            if(str.size()==0)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
                {
                    for(int j=1; j<=str.size()-i; j++)
                    {
                        cout<<str.substr(i, i+j)<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        int main()
        {
            ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
            string str;
            getline(cin, str);
            generateSubstring(str);
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but this algorithm is not at all efficient

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
def subarray(a, n) :
      for i in range(0,n):
             for j in range(i, n) :
                   for k in range(i, j+1) :
                          print(a(k), end=" ")
                   print("\n", end=" ")
a=[1, 2,3,4,5]
n=len(a)
print( all non - empty subarrays are:-)
subarray(a, n)
```

Comment: This is a O(n^3) solution, not at all efficient .

Comment: Sorry, but this algorithm is not at all efficient

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

```
function subarray(arr){
  let sub = []
  for(let i=0;i<=arr.length-1;i++){
    for(let j=arr.length-1;j>=i;j--){
      sub.push(arr.slice(i,j+1))
    }
  }
  return sub
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this algorithm is not at all efficient

Comment: @MayurAgarwal
 do you have any better solution for this, I don't see anything where we can print all the subArrays, there is a way with recursion but that can be done with O(2^n). I hope you must a better solution thats why you are able to comment on the efficiency. could you please post it?

Comment: const subArrayList = arr => {
    const subArrayList = [];

     for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
         subArrayList.push([arr[i]])

         for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++){
             subArrayList.push([...subArrayList[subArrayList.length-1],arr[j]])
         }
          
         
     }

    return subArrayList;
}

Answer (score 0):

A O(n^2) approach could be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    String res = "";
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            res += arr[j] + " ";
                System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this algorithm is not at all efficient

Comment: Your solution is not correct. It will not give all subarrays but only a subset of them.